# C++ windows has triggered a breakpoint - heap corruption

Tags: c++, windows

This error keeps being called and I can't figure out why.

[image]

Every time setNext( new Node(nullptr) ); is called this error pops up

full code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Node
{
    Node *next;
    int number;

    public:
        Node(Node *newNextNode) : next(newNextNode) { number = 0; };
        ~Node()
        {
            delete next;
        }

        int getNumber();
        void setNext(Node *newNextNode) { next = newNextNode; } ///This fails when called calling addNode()
        Node *getNext() { return next; }

};

int Node::getNumber()
{
    return number;
}


class LinkedList
{
    Node *list;

    public:
        LinkedList()
        {
            list = new Node(nullptr);
        }
        ~LinkedList()
        {
            delete list;
        }

        void addNode();
        void printList();
};

void LinkedList::addNode()
{
    Node *temp = list;

    while(temp->getNext() != nullptr)
    {
        temp = temp->getNext();
    }

    temp->setNext( new Node(nullptr) );

}

void LinkedList::printList()
{
    char *str = new char[sizeof(list->getNumber())];
    itoa(list->getNumber(), str, 10);

    Node *temp = list;

    while( temp->getNext() != nullptr )
    {
        char *c = new char[sizeof(temp->getNumber())];

        itoa( temp->getNumber(), c, 10 );

        char *tmp = new char[strlen(str) + strlen(c)];
        strcat(tmp, ' ' + c);
        strcat(tmp, str);

        str = new char[strlen(tmp)];
        strcpy(str, tmp);

        delete [] tmp;
        delete [] c;
    }

    string result(str);

    delete [] str;

    //return result;
}

int main()
{

    LinkedList *list = new LinkedList();

    list->addNode();

    list->printList();


    cin.get();

    delete list;
    return 0;
}
```

:) ok here is the full code. I know a lot of it is not the most efficient way of doing things. Ex. i'm doing printlist just to practice different things for a test.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The problem is probably in the "parts that don't matter", as it likely overwrites some data somewhere. Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that you can show us.

Comment: You have another compilation error with `newNextnode` (the last `n` should be `N`). Other than that, your code is running fine.

Comment: Sorry about that. I was trying to keep a minimal manually typed copy of the code but failed lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
char* str = new char[sizeof(list->getNumber())]
```

The expression `sizeof(list->getNumber())` is evaluated during compile-time as `sizeof(int)`.

In fact, even if it was somehow "magically" evaluated during run-time, it would still not give you the actual string-length required.

What you need is to count how many digits (including the sign if necessary) are in `number`, and then allocate the required amount plus 1 (for the null-character).

By the way, since you're doing it in C++, you might as well just use a `string`.

---

**UPDATE:**

I just noticed that you've got a bunch of other string-related problems:

- In the allocation of `char* tmp`, you should add 1 for the null-character
- You have a problem similar to the one I've mentioned, with the allocation of `char* c`
- You are reallocating `str` without deallocating it first (i.e., that will yield a memory leak)
- None of your strings is null-terminated; applying `strlen` or `strcat` on any of them will therefore yield undefined behavior (and most likely, a memory access violation at some point)

Comment: ah ok yeah I was having trouble with that part. It gives a heap error if it is char[1]. The int is only 0 but it gave an error. Is this not because of the size of int = 4 bytes vs char 1 byte?

Comment: Ah I see, do you think it is because it is a signed number? char[2] works but char[1] doesn't.

Comment: @user2654735: No, that should actually (coincidentally) work, because you are allocating more than necessary. But you still need to terminate the string with a null-character, otherwise you'll get a runtime error elsewhere.

Comment: Yeah am trying to practice the character string stuff because it is test material

Comment: @user2654735: You've got a bunch of other problems there. Please see updated answer. I think you should learn more about the term "null-terminated string" first.

Comment: Thanks for the help! So char[1] wouldn't be enough to hold 0 + '\0' ?

Comment: @user2654735: No, you will need `char[2]` for that. And of course, you will need to make sure that `char[1] == 0`. You can set it yourself explicitly in order to ensure that (although some string functions like `strcpy` and `strcat` do it for you). For example, `tmp[1] = 0` or `tmp[1] = '\0'` (both are equivalent).

Comment: You are awesome thank you so much! +1 from me for sure. Time to go back to the books

Comment: @user2654735: Haha, you're welcome. Don't forget to click on the V next to the answer before you leave :)

Answer (score 0):

This line looks suspicious:

```
char *str = new char[sizeof(list->getNumber())];
```

Assuming an `sizeof(int)` is 4 bytes, that means you are allocating a string that can only hold 3 characters plus an ending null char.

Typically, when I need to quickly allocate space to hold an integer converted to string, I'll multiple `sizeof() * 5`.  That should be large enough to hold any base 10 string for any value of any integer type including negative values.  Hence this is your new line:

```
char *str = new char[5*sizeof(list->getNumber())];
```